# Infinitely Print Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox (1/(2^n))

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

[Wikipedia: Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox)

> An infinite number of mathematicians walk into a bar. The first one orders a beer. The second one orders half a beer. The third one orders a fourth of a beer. The bartender stops them, pours two beers and says, "You're all a bunch of idiots."
>
> [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/1423a4/an_infinite_number_of_mathematicians_walk_into_a/)

Print the following series for as long as the program runs, with the denominator of each item being multiplied by two each time:

`1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + ...`

As `n` approaches infinity, the sum of this sequence approaches `2`.

## Rules

No, you may not print `2`.

You may not print `1/1` as the first item.

You may remove spaces `1+1/2+...` or add spaces `1 + 1 / 2 + ...` as you need.

You may use newlines instead of spaces as a delimiter due to popular demand.

You may append a `.` plus a constant number of `0`s to the denominator if need be.

"Infinitely" means no unnecessary delays, and for as long as possible limited by the current (variable) system's specs, but not limited by your current language.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?answertab=votes#tab-top) apply.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Regarding the joke, I like the "You guys should know your limits" version better.

Comment: Is it just me, or is that a parabola right [there](http://imgur.com/a/ohcFI)?

Comment: @StephenS Yes, I saw them too, but this one is much clearer and bigger.

Comment: What is meant by "limited by your current language."? Does that mean that any language which contains no reference to something like "Integer.MAX_VALUE" can be treated as having no max int value? Or does your "current language" include information in all compilers for said language?

Comment: @Shufflepants your program shouldn't break at a certain point based on its language. I.e., in Java, you have to use BigInteger and not int.

Comment: @Adám: yep! If the lengths of the denominators weren't changing, then the visual pattern of `+1/`s would just form a diagonal line. However, the lengths of the denominators is changing linearly (up to rounding): the number of digits of `2^n` is about `n log(2)/log(10)`. That linear change translates into a *linear* change in the *relative* position of each `+1/` with respect to the preceding one, which is the same as a *quadratic* change in the *absolute* position.

Comment: @StephenS What about C? Making it go "infinitely" there is a significantly more complicated challenge than it is in languages with a built-in BigInteger; to answer in C, we'd have to either write our on BigInteger or do all the multiplications in the string -- neither of which is easy or short.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes then you are non-competing - but if multiple people want to post competing C answers, you can compete against each other :)

Comment: Can the output have trailing zeros? `1 + 1/2.0000 + 1/4.0000 ...`

Comment: @EngineerToast is the number of trailing zeroes consistent across outputs (i.e. `1+1/2.0+1/4.0+1/8.0`) or does it increase for each output (i.e. `1+1/2.0+1/4.00+1/8.000`)? First would be OK, second would not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*

```
[No…+1/J?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x/tl/@oYZm2ob6X/f//AA)

**Explanation**

```
[           # loop over N infinitely [0 ...]
 No         # calculate 2^N
   …+1/J    # join with the string "+1/"
        ?   # print without newline
```

Comment: You can golf this: `[No?…+1/?`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: True! I knew that interpolation looked wasteful :P

Comment: Technically you should be using `«` instead of `J` but this works too.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer 'should use' isn't in a golfer's dictionary.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

-5 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```python
i=1
while 1:print i,'+1/';i*=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59pa8hVnpGZk6pgaFVQlJlXopCpo65tqK9unalla/T/PwA)

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 60 bytes

```c
f(){for(long long n=1;n;n*=2)printf(&"+1/%llu"[n^1?0:3],n);}
```

Goes up the the unsigned 64bit limit.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#LYzLDoIwEEX/pQmm00eEpiTFOvgjbmojoQkCgXFl/GzXWIzLe8/J2Qa0PvpHSCNP8Oqmhcc@LIKQieutkszPT1p5QgIlpCS0zg8Y1nlJI3X8QIpVx2JliiTu/GwbgL2S96CN15ra5EFQW5tLrgoSpqidjCqi2GFt1O8urMukKqVtTvwvaptFySOWAP69bZ9x0jHE/v4F)

This one goes on forever; (it's as small as it's going to get)

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), <s>312</s> <s>264</s> <s>255</s> <s>251</s> <s>233</s> <s>231</s> <s>208</s> <s>204</s> <s>195</s> <s>190</s> <s>188</s> 170 bytes

```c
l=4;c;main(i){for(char*t="*\b1+";puts(i=t),*++t=48;l=asprintf(&t,"1/%s",t+=*++t<49))for(t+=l-2;--t>i;)*t>52?*t=*t*2%58+c,c=*--t>52,*t=*t%48*2%10+49:(*t=*t*2-48+c+(c=0));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-tcc#LYzLDoIwEEX/pQmm00eEpiTFOvgjbmojoQkCgXFl/GzXWIzLe8/J2Qa0PvpHSCNP8Oqmhcc@LIKQieutkszPT1p5QgIlpCS0zg8Y1nlJI3X8QIpVx2JliiTu/GwbgL2S96CN15ra5EFQW5tLrgoSpqidjCqi2GFt1O8urMukKqVtTvwvaptFySOWAP69bZ9x0jHE/v4F)

Here's the not so golfed version;

```c
c;l=4;main(i){
    for(char*t="*\b1+";puts(i=t),*++t=48;l=asprintf(&t,"1/%s",t+=*++t<49))
        for(t+=l-2;--t>i;)
            *t>52?*t=*t*2%58+c,c=*--t>52,*t=*t%48*2%10+49:(*t=*t*2-48+c+(c=0));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

More fun if `⎕FR` (**F**loating-point **R**epresentation) is `1287` (128 bit decimal) and `⎕PP` (**P**rint **P**recision) is 34.

```apl
{∇2×⊃⎕←⍵'+1/'}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9Q31S3oUdsEQyMLc65HHe1RqXn5/6uBjPJHXYsf9c4DSqlrG@qr6zzqnVoO5Bgdnv6od2stRMbwP1Dhf5AWAA)

`{`…`}1` apply the following function on the number 1:

`⎕←⍵'+1/'` print the argument and the the string

`⊃` pick the first one (i.e. the argument)

`2×` double that

`∇` tail call recursion on that (optimised, so it can be infinitely repeated)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
‘;“+1/”ȮḢḤ’ß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AR0A4v//4oCYO@KAnCsxL@KAnciu4bii4bik4oCZw5///w)

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
.V0^2b"+1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyth#@68XZhBnlKSkbaj//z8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 33 bytes

```bash
echo 1;yes|awk '{print"+1/"2^NR}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@anJGvYGhdmVpck1ieraBeXVCUmVeipG2or2QU5xdUq/7/PwA)

Change `print` for `printf` and `echo` for `printf` to avoid newline

Comment: `printf 1` also avoids the newline, no?

Comment: On my Awk (GNU Awk 4.2.1), I get repeated `+1/inf` from the 1024th term onwards.  :-(

Answer (score 6):

## dc, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
1[rdp+[+1/]Prdx]dx
```

### Explanation

We push `1` and `[rdp+[+1/]Prdx]` onto the stack.  We then duplicate and execute `[rdp+[+1/]Prdx]`.  The first thing it does is to rotate the stack (`r`) so that the value is on top.  `dp+` prints the value and adds itself (to multiply by 2).  `[+1/]P` prints the invariant `+1/`, then we rotate the arguments so the saved macro definition is at the top, duplicate it and start again.

### Notes

GNU `dc` will normally wrap at 70 columns.  To override that and get an infinite line, add `DC_LINE_LENGTH=0` to your environment variables.

### Output (partial)

```
1
+1/2
+1/4
+1/8
+1/16
+1/32
+1/64
+1/128
+1/256
+1/512
+1/1024
+1/2048
+1/4096
+1/8192
+1/16384
+1/32768
+1/65536
+1/131072
+1/262144
+1/524288
+1/1048576
+1/2097152
+1/4194304
+1/8388608
```

...

```
+1/1042962419883256876169444192465601618458351817556959360325703910069443225478828393565899456512
+1/2085924839766513752338888384931203236916703635113918720651407820138886450957656787131798913024
+1/4171849679533027504677776769862406473833407270227837441302815640277772901915313574263597826048
+1/8343699359066055009355553539724812947666814540455674882605631280555545803830627148527195652096
+1/16687398718132110018711107079449625895333629080911349765211262561111091607661254297054391304192
+1/33374797436264220037422214158899251790667258161822699530422525122222183215322508594108782608384
```

...

```
+1/395087429607039737016990582493211473623084548479366958355967894445617992237751193831383393115316177621785336292974757702861456280882511441699391271295733513512496264566385933380947965261723454959331220707759295808360415615991592990777778282040705827434949633856633176265789944580636935948031966453153742439217291986581128250733429493898120451931770274751229567569237843273729615827100381825373339221412595529512989073039623048380802736380367607801160720048450955272332555885534822792967746973597821924656959979423188656952212441297346660701518718326620774081406711639289159232374325676221430645461061339419517215005226454502285089841722594900476336947000733101279737598704985318796279216595068894677898277722179745279389210632125609476578229717704884251829483656808483833708957351468743071618868390065369478551657766868765417931368111672635805713040939576059856661966901849284974427853607640934780174510177467344954981530954324587346785943498033783853652888777144814836577685249298036748395273293867889213776236596621464513866240966454560881624123468744072759399999977952917047275150817022801141959157607304299710040536803961941539248511838228140896285208917844516516354328828341895189859625184919137459427696083645173496443173168837863941880276763158758023006149415211675330687766377148229974279566049003264864600191840267483777843342674487811516073311635515312490178552895957423373899881643180029114753167161849015185102165069678102141792645820016416047568386145306495107877487105159701033434133879076295235543592729076137504220533421618969333525966517622043110194920864084904515587227955524573123041514933277200135397957913967801292194452638091786561237904399020102666362253691989299390107684868894715745836877407032377238840608843413131092703960427769853699078374834491936996044463254349297156213103279673169178505184701872144900045771102435610296184197209227529288007415067046022722582981596269522005749627981773526366438220575437177263889604130699335432595226257543492333263422050922067270179224260275144056594379835114406083447004727056013389366056869669871721247387721885160070482303207498193981625368149767105925975387341377059500273590145880590627076202552189658057673577965137474478445230279151378408213456608653443746420052642315479741917201353741316367530727339674720984684319607014456047714106368632178729336223365487529774958557802515621876807522117219692963254636001726226095376131918803784811313633676500693288681886899229878108736316145573597053282102794465392580102681361770473681924380592794825281026389925319284295575976905371805098869309557779427667880257736023553969079065990247752442478709560271890544575319753044785213713815214853531493050977096589318122209182622944866896029727456835427297057238010067400316328458733735151924868494740318125717480345439976856588095695103557933254518724035147790867900860802490856266882895272405233909349503100342835778128113450704055933916580251051242513114247923234285375218348330984968499261151666279876934252251642210658880406798177100551493117002184732295738827350073267361848262282761987958004309963517948938698786164969644086580797555934352507402669257430636696930339621666387272089588481086182797065416819524024244039514527278555283258634786254208521110348742241263325816002709937195402337679130173170319173019473143013813053957781486624112400998612123509635383191611221055251405429574982431605111210811909998737934637009821942743916100790356493781569074043021092914565490511459722069379412568362070588905824887062692251966557571063144913628359617852782242850667347243493635423170856735991445443417871593754841930126545261100978250334790401134417708085254996280546469054953434698740338004535923304134925010294666195488077033498408573400230908456372758784275514839518209197168385986800728708864486555574751038959875865944573232904382772174165469240721191260083414343513721167588202103644839217795869540476457367497547061295275817063645407861999254441068513089288941238387198872484274061935238732418142521129602424711571463536885701004481109813887972526424268833936301999940489737888191570936888484964073548401260573294755586807219169314540668429632835157545851763722427756273879072731431505757610169922077517245770967529970605394054778171352769192297060429577138791870011615935227225671201093581479973265123899759178588060627003483624484718952553536175080141557411018195112843918387330586945434704681386712037849132186150132261042825792865372648754304087311364485783913995232206503295131703588146450037893765442335625163597434960232164031867939806213034434955304659392517248083742743104580255027984810817258473711668510466293353159230682507713356536346933373222621074069493621551732890007902642898203729353535541505055230646447927335528957518174124051240324790069803454443268705032437412987085956986231654396653945449361791419385673388462153863206838157383577706049673416137197255949136605805960826652037358130882947815724836422987739828579124410515444240566417712451706437934444715054112852437374620837818318965333233036720725057182268814289785426876890730560232557019341916693475054757150722335726164285001394620207185098209060247075408696040161086332399037926647184391403995691066367778171562567400295434214765373073532471221761418214238803246752363904522571261072568011082281025572468893579252790734242527127778212414258417151636760753113090140644900683087184729743937692882688781682528416310850143754232086010450547458252820624921499276046395019090380887163852054555145431526258731837552253081278815739277412689465695941457195947520449547528479195654921291630947757961099209920460560771007698446991318388178005121886864829789281989687868033416542896922010329803510712241486910230176578077334774066133073728498756538589509813926190053693968878600638282582915610844019713891397117761984470765139228094313389312619025293455644485019485659751869296503689550132880058360683768191850360853185346730443998577670217447676572006007846832281428067265029500735963006405097225737892017644266262369462412574469988693558883982457143609025342185734610083070158152370952984896142295431884162794373897052159892645389273308325006511838982963210612512322440419463781685703879460818754246754737940067675306280339905099665753185624213049959974358988865877958103529903146946530778345631329029194118707823987745182366133711832776917746326752560414432248765580001690261776455186768733481157296158946100861665048300648945542904325905584298490513362292415753190834332376223017933102895303381625772236869056493905619864331052324553111223626084907937012036147356323467349271564345943614252673724659330963224126235367389507942684619417763187571792457049977423564605600407492739749810469638764253641886550627347410736476168235036323056296424076410773881349066193975356477998788704088168252906853359434516247984743194831348262718121306661583008435884810496549588343058262321647390735264606206072011103907091768882769468469548172289382501112430456154299134997391379920716169599617338345446024206416533732905022779643316661925667780044405263747380549446190984315096751598520871084659561682150880941631909886116710336501837005063103142970019870229280161913535898896273821723701749825424198801867406788183134913924263719112061721504776882103064064359808662664627132885266814050508776452910137134270723647297071012906850061114810029573681278211481183908305090518470607821191868530182355469879320671285317749034490711147615749836523756450457907560809808180752736277635732973149879636046843370244031978388137905356568834841691405960511052920098099303117458443459752992376005588918461949244074455720525010639887497443006893435915417651916819463649597517491710312592729976616519543890099530933526832155577274386878813332226092536388499227272797049735342204092718218399418943214483876032335170210620818582577397681191807311146697580973912033655792648256970866595194893815163653986467309514803085649995372052311880524198806710857097759813038371950266290297264677343705141037392715602877631695706464175624716337179764939952510203992806290410817066938678282725721991737936771618886658531530432671336707243253399686635114284033467196647570867723924592346710336310499837157847001000657477981583545401290986926236963825871995956812647720239548464931532537453731179201219809243551668681899320550475784370849798950308066492614030400947685348077036376906960967572117048503094709377111019534286030732015239027627742931733097540469889785438409079499563218182778062136770448874634337602252200785481498083800414471627026908575019040813241133085007748236210770824190826032543188084102056377610344497047314070899072279218186771810995166773473114538521089207373662535516843804894247865222415416567979253467876905240369631759382670743540819101472322524971913190038014207087495403005280426785325932475391049960936934038679922250485974423425021273852536322945163397389403648570637150505325367515540775710473683840127830499238530870104153509651904712990936272485771980487060597330426352158711289651715205689049260499430924095066894960045670014855252638636173892541721664064657257545484662281992727145339820179787932300136239018814532042680306206506846252926868289215506270940648380151080863903543873800421024947008029227493253733743659931460789009603522492213592492048391771760673166705432907234322574655099086321398830175703899404965151123193886696442296349071654094637032308306856955288952171834242794325316103826542731616585851913306273167685606136686470354702529673355285989172690078260014657789396032732932707667614838197171927208752920806753147947753042162645589267309328014049843059474903297455903512702132260588248559475081881636853227563097955967083889828222963665998878755153458074282990405836509465604418489946220280072051695243646682126417012619626420434704676470720900405053137991022528724677776185782640188543273087475178910478479476375475107166115050700098469965773154824987334911488998504643031126617426087742334881528986730831286510376127857270260065953591254351135389978509155685077650175013516418689843888963267814029997035174397017156131402312672241612206597456154522391107951335408620230202536389665726663417780482765640799333938105922754878613702760187032743689376707408517940178159467558086798870508509302008010853150053660329410964652409126276870654180681874881929746118180582577305743743952810779398262012426174907734327106136327201729744548683488487099663898103452434942210300833833130143850134675972327857405316343100019819653706594138235142730877703690741728508059492138642914276288984044042099728558960754700526065507631173050607164329771213342522618716881636690451903407693545135452815509580836160948812037959966193150381363591325661363476282370880535386441056486977358792737573438415565582362150808790336607040072093996865509619115356670599413230372818843108462117192738018820456322869946146303496007938903379241735817413492283835977534999446414774242209937016102619721220743544264050400097257089329412409254182040067187294506795767071674839385327568309523275288224086341778500123181829914635212704885959073672849205647176312287693211208290617090697646296209359258826200442497277991265116001163923419756327042484575648575021801534747270301153864412881912695313170393490767798464601324811063517942109518188821662675241828342647930010935849739305511205479557635171775009458846115428296418509860882903797249010462815241310630703763917719343099389989212618131651857779639943520010464854895769226125734400676226305595574413150903275614989606378324476097633897174939587875967658516048531378475872344597620732910259889372637316612851578821200108167426224067862632022377346659611324512681594932786190395749866081212126765942648631311170725777632375318331458676692976060778353923365207931601783140329977239640697677390642952067751304225189275891914656263416947084450120234441671746028997201191323195215386733714871687707800672016820227681962426204834017171078741804363016905452036367437049026691141558129758797699640194324162736418976728910597423824473007553073364103514575141561781882871644975070955229562369626756867869338986838760342284146441315204683418587181558372435743877156433485354976428152730039744389279516110761771426764201299330794471271711515888964165405659366091810847151036007173905114063582213623053963744257889874028150526901847782612540828524150747603549047215293759454581158155329597162690004775971455898321404025294368662413692106436456898487879798453482089212957398027468299542185050952024424434257748368440629523534889927058704389099405555033480560657504105905182439365431354241976084762913941805532894762520886571190102966212136887152569491150928851182909057450691899990027643415972827215164457661126843197212359209124565023629842753704005053902959730902144697324536284243222516487451881162143985260026576702277354398701943268311327348278723577644934801132856940314800246225039733533484807420506534462368695104335500466194188432862110475125223174190441086648726124829278566262264102582145477455790001229962128988151514777487437037270487153943987721550211938223551105161674656128149829492208549801379399145307479176248550539143187103073739912305990874163539516471346476299608693068764303029104908023285789101921870714244184682024700760361462663101570206457539892273492121502188312469283565918477771845191345920751263742268857954344987825767697329023593992910217713704972512065484949552264125935161622986929633713130569797577128578214458329586269690647799782014649930675405127944876912350950231416318397349447230393724491695757547080501396519382299957816346147421987910768628451509475789472047213399478200233594932011006341697414362898632815522642132016614650400350428923555620918057200926864089035767073332791867816685434096971239607592477801325642486235952866653992824568229542798606247131414859323219085694179902810098535657962013883197934894815206949876469106535355971101217848490155179261164663801145917802217034896618411596621165894170862154553621702226207363854759575529806758207708865406552630203012980490505941247406029120385466493805043607084819136763318505396587786149987409414795363172301089051894908740418011869835127044174788340738050919777596148274325858751879060573875387047962263073964078212858407556731801896720172173402451609345514653369843948925865731285026645995919856979876708543976520293377113985661155885697067770340963454255462317778374708234636608739119582761909701893485235072604937207880557091958509260575756938640165512270322212561952906328322017549014849215824787611893951617083671247652355225313571195438343636594795213938009780362376632674524801606712889751259220696409500370952911456813275349818073892021046409289255786132787385187019129176514080173483822613572793996361788110041096484931301484233630238022334653847275796035554791678720054505018864099939754669651544296841730613206450101627744726143047203934946454579761956034246397049238954525292315292293731998279977819953334814618383443186382455045395596531660361384999262672019010927022846744105110180629489154477796693814515782860555654300726449058256946453431271071240673715129993027272108615147743053163012016539090192335094681890199309163850322423174196757401200305496025245970076637786182016385654479388672
+1/790174859214079474033981164986422947246169096958733916711935788891235984475502387662766786230632355243570672585949515405722912561765022883398782542591467027024992529132771866761895930523446909918662441415518591616720831231983185981555556564081411654869899267713266352531579889161273871896063932906307484878434583973162256501466858987796240903863540549502459135138475686547459231654200763650746678442825191059025978146079246096761605472760735215602321440096901910544665111771069645585935493947195643849313919958846377313904424882594693321403037436653241548162813423278578318464748651352442861290922122678839034430010452909004570179683445189800952673894001466202559475197409970637592558433190137789355796555444359490558778421264251218953156459435409768503658967313616967667417914702937486143237736780130738957103315533737530835862736223345271611426081879152119713323933803698569948855707215281869560349020354934689909963061908649174693571886996067567707305777554289629673155370498596073496790546587735778427552473193242929027732481932909121763248246937488145518799999955905834094550301634045602283918315214608599420081073607923883078497023676456281792570417835689033032708657656683790379719250369838274918855392167290346992886346337675727883760553526317516046012298830423350661375532754296459948559132098006529729200383680534967555686685348975623032146623271030624980357105791914846747799763286360058229506334323698030370204330139356204283585291640032832095136772290612990215754974210319402066868267758152590471087185458152275008441066843237938667051933035244086220389841728169809031174455911049146246083029866554400270795915827935602584388905276183573122475808798040205332724507383978598780215369737789431491673754814064754477681217686826262185407920855539707398156749668983873992088926508698594312426206559346338357010369403744289800091542204871220592368394418455058576014830134092045445165963192539044011499255963547052732876441150874354527779208261398670865190452515086984666526844101844134540358448520550288113188759670228812166894009454112026778732113739339743442494775443770320140964606414996387963250736299534211851950774682754119000547180291761181254152405104379316115347155930274948956890460558302756816426913217306887492840105284630959483834402707482632735061454679349441969368639214028912095428212737264357458672446730975059549917115605031243753615044234439385926509272003452452190752263837607569622627267353001386577363773798459756217472632291147194106564205588930785160205362723540947363848761185589650562052779850638568591151953810743610197738619115558855335760515472047107938158131980495504884957419120543781089150639506089570427427630429707062986101954193178636244418365245889733792059454913670854594114476020134800632656917467470303849736989480636251434960690879953713176191390207115866509037448070295581735801721604981712533765790544810467818699006200685671556256226901408111867833160502102485026228495846468570750436696661969936998522303332559753868504503284421317760813596354201102986234004369464591477654700146534723696524565523975916008619927035897877397572329939288173161595111868705014805338514861273393860679243332774544179176962172365594130833639048048488079029054557110566517269572508417042220697484482526651632005419874390804675358260346340638346038946286027626107915562973248224801997224247019270766383222442110502810859149964863210222421623819997475869274019643885487832201580712987563138148086042185829130981022919444138758825136724141177811649774125384503933115142126289827256719235705564485701334694486987270846341713471982890886835743187509683860253090522201956500669580802268835416170509992561092938109906869397480676009071846608269850020589332390976154066996817146800461816912745517568551029679036418394336771973601457417728973111149502077919751731889146465808765544348330938481442382520166828687027442335176404207289678435591739080952914734995094122590551634127290815723998508882137026178577882476774397744968548123870477464836285042259204849423142927073771402008962219627775945052848537667872603999880979475776383141873776969928147096802521146589511173614438338629081336859265670315091703527444855512547758145462863011515220339844155034491541935059941210788109556342705538384594120859154277583740023231870454451342402187162959946530247799518357176121254006967248969437905107072350160283114822036390225687836774661173890869409362773424075698264372300264522085651585730745297508608174622728971567827990464413006590263407176292900075787530884671250327194869920464328063735879612426068869910609318785034496167485486209160510055969621634516947423337020932586706318461365015426713072693866746445242148138987243103465780015805285796407458707071083010110461292895854671057915036348248102480649580139606908886537410064874825974171913972463308793307890898723582838771346776924307726413676314767155412099346832274394511898273211611921653304074716261765895631449672845975479657158248821030888481132835424903412875868889430108225704874749241675636637930666466073441450114364537628579570853753781461120465114038683833386950109514301444671452328570002789240414370196418120494150817392080322172664798075853294368782807991382132735556343125134800590868429530746147064942443522836428477606493504727809045142522145136022164562051144937787158505581468485054255556424828516834303273521506226180281289801366174369459487875385765377563365056832621700287508464172020901094916505641249842998552092790038180761774327704109110290863052517463675104506162557631478554825378931391882914391895040899095056958391309842583261895515922198419840921121542015396893982636776356010243773729659578563979375736066833085793844020659607021424482973820460353156154669548132266147456997513077179019627852380107387937757201276565165831221688039427782794235523968941530278456188626778625238050586911288970038971319503738593007379100265760116721367536383700721706370693460887997155340434895353144012015693664562856134530059001471926012810194451475784035288532524738924825148939977387117767964914287218050684371469220166140316304741905969792284590863768325588747794104319785290778546616650013023677965926421225024644880838927563371407758921637508493509475880135350612560679810199331506371248426099919948717977731755916207059806293893061556691262658058388237415647975490364732267423665553835492653505120828864497531160003380523552910373537466962314592317892201723330096601297891085808651811168596981026724584831506381668664752446035866205790606763251544473738112987811239728662104649106222447252169815874024072294712646934698543128691887228505347449318661926448252470734779015885369238835526375143584914099954847129211200814985479499620939277528507283773101254694821472952336470072646112592848152821547762698132387950712955997577408176336505813706718869032495969486389662696525436242613323166016871769620993099176686116524643294781470529212412144022207814183537765538936939096344578765002224860912308598269994782759841432339199234676690892048412833067465810045559286633323851335560088810527494761098892381968630193503197041742169319123364301761883263819772233420673003674010126206285940039740458560323827071797792547643447403499650848397603734813576366269827848527438224123443009553764206128128719617325329254265770533628101017552905820274268541447294594142025813700122229620059147362556422962367816610181036941215642383737060364710939758641342570635498068981422295231499673047512900915815121619616361505472555271465946299759272093686740488063956776275810713137669683382811921022105840196198606234916886919505984752011177836923898488148911441050021279774994886013786871830835303833638927299195034983420625185459953233039087780199061867053664311154548773757626664452185072776998454545594099470684408185436436798837886428967752064670340421241637165154795362383614622293395161947824067311585296513941733190389787630327307972934619029606171299990744104623761048397613421714195519626076743900532580594529354687410282074785431205755263391412928351249432674359529879905020407985612580821634133877356565451443983475873543237773317063060865342673414486506799373270228568066934393295141735447849184693420672620999674315694002001314955963167090802581973852473927651743991913625295440479096929863065074907462358402439618487103337363798641100951568741699597900616132985228060801895370696154072753813921935144234097006189418754222039068572061464030478055255485863466195080939779570876818158999126436365556124273540897749268675204504401570962996167600828943254053817150038081626482266170015496472421541648381652065086376168204112755220688994094628141798144558436373543621990333546946229077042178414747325071033687609788495730444830833135958506935753810480739263518765341487081638202944645049943826380076028414174990806010560853570651864950782099921873868077359844500971948846850042547705072645890326794778807297141274301010650735031081551420947367680255660998477061740208307019303809425981872544971543960974121194660852704317422579303430411378098520998861848190133789920091340029710505277272347785083443328129314515090969324563985454290679640359575864600272478037629064085360612413013692505853736578431012541881296760302161727807087747600842049894016058454986507467487319862921578019207044984427184984096783543521346333410865814468645149310198172642797660351407798809930302246387773392884592698143308189274064616613713910577904343668485588650632207653085463233171703826612546335371212273372940709405059346710571978345380156520029315578792065465865415335229676394343854417505841613506295895506084325291178534618656028099686118949806594911807025404264521176497118950163763273706455126195911934167779656445927331997757510306916148565980811673018931208836979892440560144103390487293364252834025239252840869409352941441800810106275982045057449355552371565280377086546174950357820956958952750950214332230101400196939931546309649974669822977997009286062253234852175484669763057973461662573020752255714540520131907182508702270779957018311370155300350027032837379687777926535628059994070348794034312262804625344483224413194912309044782215902670817240460405072779331453326835560965531281598667876211845509757227405520374065487378753414817035880356318935116173597741017018604016021706300107320658821929304818252553741308361363749763859492236361165154611487487905621558796524024852349815468654212272654403459489097366976974199327796206904869884420601667666260287700269351944655714810632686200039639307413188276470285461755407381483457016118984277285828552577968088084199457117921509401052131015262346101214328659542426685045237433763273380903806815387090270905631019161672321897624075919932386300762727182651322726952564741761070772882112973954717585475146876831131164724301617580673214080144187993731019238230713341198826460745637686216924234385476037640912645739892292606992015877806758483471634826984567671955069998892829548484419874032205239442441487088528100800194514178658824818508364080134374589013591534143349678770655136619046550576448172683557000246363659829270425409771918147345698411294352624575386422416581234181395292592418718517652400884994555982530232002327846839512654084969151297150043603069494540602307728825763825390626340786981535596929202649622127035884219036377643325350483656685295860021871699478611022410959115270343550018917692230856592837019721765807594498020925630482621261407527835438686198779978425236263303715559279887040020929709791538452251468801352452611191148826301806551229979212756648952195267794349879175751935317032097062756951744689195241465820519778745274633225703157642400216334852448135725264044754693319222649025363189865572380791499732162424253531885297262622341451555264750636662917353385952121556707846730415863203566280659954479281395354781285904135502608450378551783829312526833894168900240468883343492057994402382646390430773467429743375415601344033640455363924852409668034342157483608726033810904072734874098053382283116259517595399280388648325472837953457821194847648946015106146728207029150283123563765743289950141910459124739253513735738677973677520684568292882630409366837174363116744871487754312866970709952856305460079488778559032221523542853528402598661588942543423031777928330811318732183621694302072014347810228127164427246107927488515779748056301053803695565225081657048301495207098094430587518909162316310659194325380009551942911796642808050588737324827384212872913796975759596906964178425914796054936599084370101904048848868515496736881259047069779854117408778198811110066961121315008211810364878730862708483952169525827883611065789525041773142380205932424273774305138982301857702365818114901383799980055286831945654430328915322253686394424718418249130047259685507408010107805919461804289394649072568486445032974903762324287970520053153404554708797403886536622654696557447155289869602265713880629600492450079467066969614841013068924737390208671000932388376865724220950250446348380882173297452249658557132524528205164290954911580002459924257976303029554974874074540974307887975443100423876447102210323349312256299658984417099602758798290614958352497101078286374206147479824611981748327079032942692952599217386137528606058209816046571578203843741428488369364049401520722925326203140412915079784546984243004376624938567131836955543690382691841502527484537715908689975651535394658047187985820435427409945024130969899104528251870323245973859267426261139595154257156428916659172539381295599564029299861350810255889753824701900462832636794698894460787448983391515094161002793038764599915632692294843975821537256903018951578944094426798956400467189864022012683394828725797265631045284264033229300800700857847111241836114401853728178071534146665583735633370868193942479215184955602651284972471905733307985649136459085597212494262829718646438171388359805620197071315924027766395869789630413899752938213070711942202435696980310358522329327602291835604434069793236823193242331788341724309107243404452414727709519151059613516415417730813105260406025960981011882494812058240770932987610087214169638273526637010793175572299974818829590726344602178103789817480836023739670254088349576681476101839555192296548651717503758121147750774095924526147928156425716815113463603793440344346804903218691029306739687897851731462570053291991839713959753417087953040586754227971322311771394135540681926908510924635556749416469273217478239165523819403786970470145209874415761114183917018521151513877280331024540644425123905812656644035098029698431649575223787903234167342495304710450627142390876687273189590427876019560724753265349049603213425779502518441392819000741905822913626550699636147784042092818578511572265574770374038258353028160346967645227145587992723576220082192969862602968467260476044669307694551592071109583357440109010037728199879509339303088593683461226412900203255489452286094407869892909159523912068492794098477909050584630584587463996559955639906669629236766886372764910090791193063320722769998525344038021854045693488210220361258978308955593387629031565721111308601452898116513892906862542142481347430259986054544217230295486106326024033078180384670189363780398618327700644846348393514802400610992050491940153275572364032771308958777344
+1/1580349718428158948067962329972845894492338193917467833423871577782471968951004775325533572461264710487141345171899030811445825123530045766797565085182934054049985058265543733523791861046893819837324882831037183233441662463966371963111113128162823309739798535426532705063159778322547743792127865812614969756869167946324513002933717975592481807727081099004918270276951373094918463308401527301493356885650382118051956292158492193523210945521470431204642880193803821089330223542139291171870987894391287698627839917692754627808849765189386642806074873306483096325626846557156636929497302704885722581844245357678068860020905818009140359366890379601905347788002932405118950394819941275185116866380275578711593110888718981117556842528502437906312918870819537007317934627233935334835829405874972286475473560261477914206631067475061671725472446690543222852163758304239426647867607397139897711414430563739120698040709869379819926123817298349387143773992135135414611555108579259346310740997192146993581093175471556855104946386485858055464963865818243526496493874976291037599999911811668189100603268091204567836630429217198840162147215847766156994047352912563585140835671378066065417315313367580759438500739676549837710784334580693985772692675351455767521107052635032092024597660846701322751065508592919897118264196013059458400767361069935111373370697951246064293246542061249960714211583829693495599526572720116459012668647396060740408660278712408567170583280065664190273544581225980431509948420638804133736535516305180942174370916304550016882133686475877334103866070488172440779683456339618062348911822098292492166059733108800541591831655871205168777810552367146244951617596080410665449014767957197560430739475578862983347509628129508955362435373652524370815841711079414796313499337967747984177853017397188624852413118692676714020738807488579600183084409742441184736788836910117152029660268184090890331926385078088022998511927094105465752882301748709055558416522797341730380905030173969333053688203688269080716897041100576226377519340457624333788018908224053557464227478679486884989550887540640281929212829992775926501472599068423703901549365508238001094360583522362508304810208758632230694311860549897913780921116605513632853826434613774985680210569261918967668805414965265470122909358698883938737278428057824190856425474528714917344893461950119099834231210062487507230088468878771853018544006904904381504527675215139245254534706002773154727547596919512434945264582294388213128411177861570320410725447081894727697522371179301124105559701277137182303907621487220395477238231117710671521030944094215876316263960991009769914838241087562178301279012179140854855260859414125972203908386357272488836730491779467584118909827341709188228952040269601265313834934940607699473978961272502869921381759907426352382780414231733018074896140591163471603443209963425067531581089620935637398012401371343112512453802816223735666321004204970052456991692937141500873393323939873997044606665119507737009006568842635521627192708402205972468008738929182955309400293069447393049131047951832017239854071795754795144659878576346323190223737410029610677029722546787721358486665549088358353924344731188261667278096096976158058109114221133034539145016834084441394968965053303264010839748781609350716520692681276692077892572055252215831125946496449603994448494038541532766444884221005621718299929726420444843247639994951738548039287770975664403161425975126276296172084371658261962045838888277517650273448282355623299548250769007866230284252579654513438471411128971402669388973974541692683426943965781773671486375019367720506181044403913001339161604537670832341019985122185876219813738794961352018143693216539700041178664781952308133993634293600923633825491035137102059358072836788673543947202914835457946222299004155839503463778292931617531088696661876962884765040333657374054884670352808414579356871183478161905829469990188245181103268254581631447997017764274052357155764953548795489937096247740954929672570084518409698846285854147542804017924439255551890105697075335745207999761958951552766283747553939856294193605042293179022347228876677258162673718531340630183407054889711025095516290925726023030440679688310068983083870119882421576219112685411076769188241718308555167480046463740908902684804374325919893060495599036714352242508013934497938875810214144700320566229644072780451375673549322347781738818725546848151396528744600529044171303171461490595017216349245457943135655980928826013180526814352585800151575061769342500654389739840928656127471759224852137739821218637570068992334970972418321020111939243269033894846674041865173412636922730030853426145387733492890484296277974486206931560031610571592814917414142166020220922585791709342115830072696496204961299160279213817773074820129749651948343827944926617586615781797447165677542693553848615452827352629534310824198693664548789023796546423223843306608149432523531791262899345691950959314316497642061776962265670849806825751737778860216451409749498483351273275861332932146882900228729075257159141707507562922240930228077367666773900219028602889342904657140005578480828740392836240988301634784160644345329596151706588737565615982764265471112686250269601181736859061492294129884887045672856955212987009455618090285044290272044329124102289875574317011162936970108511112849657033668606547043012452360562579602732348738918975750771530755126730113665243400575016928344041802189833011282499685997104185580076361523548655408218220581726105034927350209012325115262957109650757862783765828783790081798190113916782619685166523791031844396839681842243084030793787965273552712020487547459319157127958751472133666171587688041319214042848965947640920706312309339096264532294913995026154358039255704760214775875514402553130331662443376078855565588471047937883060556912377253557250476101173822577940077942639007477186014758200531520233442735072767401443412741386921775994310680869790706288024031387329125712269060118002943852025620388902951568070577065049477849650297879954774235535929828574436101368742938440332280632609483811939584569181727536651177495588208639570581557093233300026047355931852842450049289761677855126742815517843275016987018951760270701225121359620398663012742496852199839897435955463511832414119612587786123113382525316116776474831295950980729464534847331107670985307010241657728995062320006761047105820747074933924629184635784403446660193202595782171617303622337193962053449169663012763337329504892071732411581213526503088947476225975622479457324209298212444894504339631748048144589425293869397086257383774457010694898637323852896504941469558031770738477671052750287169828199909694258422401629970958999241878555057014567546202509389642945904672940145292225185696305643095525396264775901425911995154816352673011627413437738064991938972779325393050872485226646332033743539241986198353372233049286589562941058424824288044415628367075531077873878192689157530004449721824617196539989565519682864678398469353381784096825666134931620091118573266647702671120177621054989522197784763937260387006394083484338638246728603523766527639544466841346007348020252412571880079480917120647654143595585095286894806999301696795207469627152732539655697054876448246886019107528412256257439234650658508531541067256202035105811640548537082894589188284051627400244459240118294725112845924735633220362073882431284767474120729421879517282685141270996137962844590462999346095025801831630243239232723010945110542931892599518544187373480976127913552551621426275339366765623842044211680392397212469833773839011969504022355673847796976297822882100042559549989772027573743661670607667277854598390069966841250370919906466078175560398123734107328622309097547515253328904370145553996909091188198941368816370872873597675772857935504129340680842483274330309590724767229244586790323895648134623170593027883466380779575260654615945869238059212342599981488209247522096795226843428391039252153487801065161189058709374820564149570862411510526782825856702498865348719059759810040815971225161643268267754713130902887966951747086475546634126121730685346828973013598746540457136133868786590283470895698369386841345241999348631388004002629911926334181605163947704947855303487983827250590880958193859726130149814924716804879236974206674727597282201903137483399195801232265970456121603790741392308145507627843870288468194012378837508444078137144122928060956110510971726932390161879559141753636317998252872731112248547081795498537350409008803141925992335201657886508107634300076163252964532340030992944843083296763304130172752336408225510441377988189256283596289116872747087243980667093892458154084356829494650142067375219576991460889661666271917013871507620961478527037530682974163276405889290099887652760152056828349981612021121707141303729901564199843747736154719689001943897693700085095410145291780653589557614594282548602021301470062163102841894735360511321996954123480416614038607618851963745089943087921948242389321705408634845158606860822756197041997723696380267579840182680059421010554544695570166886656258629030181938649127970908581359280719151729200544956075258128170721224826027385011707473156862025083762593520604323455614175495201684099788032116909973014934974639725843156038414089968854369968193567087042692666821731628937290298620396345285595320702815597619860604492775546785769185396286616378548129233227427821155808687336971177301264415306170926466343407653225092670742424546745881418810118693421143956690760313040058631157584130931730830670459352788687708835011683227012591791012168650582357069237312056199372237899613189823614050808529042352994237900327526547412910252391823868335559312891854663995515020613832297131961623346037862417673959784881120288206780974586728505668050478505681738818705882883601620212551964090114898711104743130560754173092349900715641913917905501900428664460202800393879863092619299949339645955994018572124506469704350969339526115946923325146041504511429081040263814365017404541559914036622740310600700054065674759375555853071256119988140697588068624525609250688966448826389824618089564431805341634480920810145558662906653671121931062563197335752423691019514454811040748130974757506829634071760712637870232347195482034037208032043412600214641317643858609636505107482616722727499527718984472722330309222974975811243117593048049704699630937308424545308806918978194733953948398655592413809739768841203335332520575400538703889311429621265372400079278614826376552940570923510814762966914032237968554571657105155936176168398914235843018802104262030524692202428657319084853370090474867526546761807613630774180541811262038323344643795248151839864772601525454365302645453905129483522141545764225947909435170950293753662262329448603235161346428160288375987462038476461426682397652921491275372433848468770952075281825291479784585213984031755613516966943269653969135343910139997785659096968839748064410478884882974177056201600389028357317649637016728160268749178027183068286699357541310273238093101152896345367114000492727319658540850819543836294691396822588705249150772844833162468362790585184837437035304801769989111965060464004655693679025308169938302594300087206138989081204615457651527650781252681573963071193858405299244254071768438072755286650700967313370591720043743398957222044821918230540687100037835384461713185674039443531615188996041851260965242522815055670877372397559956850472526607431118559774080041859419583076904502937602704905222382297652603613102459958425513297904390535588699758351503870634064194125513903489378390482931641039557490549266451406315284800432669704896271450528089509386638445298050726379731144761582999464324848507063770594525244682903110529501273325834706771904243113415693460831726407132561319908958562790709562571808271005216900757103567658625053667788337800480937766686984115988804765292780861546934859486750831202688067280910727849704819336068684314967217452067621808145469748196106764566232519035190798560777296650945675906915642389695297892030212293456414058300566247127531486579900283820918249478507027471477355947355041369136585765260818733674348726233489742975508625733941419905712610920158977557118064443047085707056805197323177885086846063555856661622637464367243388604144028695620456254328854492215854977031559496112602107607391130450163314096602990414196188861175037818324632621318388650760019103885823593285616101177474649654768425745827593951519193813928356851829592109873198168740203808097697737030993473762518094139559708234817556397622220133922242630016423620729757461725416967904339051655767222131579050083546284760411864848547548610277964603715404731636229802767599960110573663891308860657830644507372788849436836498260094519371014816020215611838923608578789298145136972890065949807524648575941040106306809109417594807773073245309393114894310579739204531427761259200984900158934133939229682026137849474780417342001864776753731448441900500892696761764346594904499317114265049056410328581909823160004919848515952606059109949748149081948615775950886200847752894204420646698624512599317968834199205517596581229916704994202156572748412294959649223963496654158065885385905198434772275057212116419632093143156407687482856976738728098803041445850652406280825830159569093968486008753249877134263673911087380765383683005054969075431817379951303070789316094375971640870854819890048261939798209056503740646491947718534852522279190308514312857833318345078762591199128058599722701620511779507649403800925665273589397788921574897966783030188322005586077529199831265384589687951643074513806037903157888188853597912800934379728044025366789657451594531262090568528066458601601401715694222483672228803707456356143068293331167471266741736387884958430369911205302569944943811466615971298272918171194424988525659437292876342776719611240394142631848055532791739579260827799505876426141423884404871393960620717044658655204583671208868139586473646386484663576683448618214486808904829455419038302119227032830835461626210520812051921962023764989624116481541865975220174428339276547053274021586351144599949637659181452689204356207579634961672047479340508176699153362952203679110384593097303435007516242295501548191849052295856312851433630226927207586880688693609806437382058613479375795703462925140106583983679427919506834175906081173508455942644623542788271081363853817021849271113498832938546434956478331047638807573940940290419748831522228367834037042303027754560662049081288850247811625313288070196059396863299150447575806468334684990609420901254284781753374546379180855752039121449506530698099206426851559005036882785638001483811645827253101399272295568084185637157023144531149540748076516706056320693935290454291175985447152440164385939725205936934520952089338615389103184142219166714880218020075456399759018678606177187366922452825800406510978904572188815739785818319047824136985588196955818101169261169174927993119911279813339258473533772745529820181582386126641445539997050688076043708091386976420440722517956617911186775258063131442222617202905796233027785813725084284962694860519972109088434460590972212652048066156360769340378727560797236655401289692696787029604801221984100983880306551144728065542617917554688
```

...

Comment: i was 15 minutes late T_T, use `dp` instead of `ddn` to save a byte

Comment: I used `dn` to avoid introducing a newline, but did consider `p` (at the cost of uglier output).  Actually, on reflection, it's not so ugly, after all.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (ES6)](https://babeljs.io/), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```javascript
for(a=1;;a*=2)console.log(a+'+1/')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-babel-node#TcsxDoAgDADAr7i1FVODg0vlLzSkujRiMPH76Oh@Z4865r7XhpqiiI5poVLPu7qx1wM1QIgzUM/c7HIthiAC0wCiW7RVgEj@AZj54y8)

Inspired by [Jake Taylor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120839/69074).

Note that this is limited by language since `a` is a floating-point variable, not an integer.

-2 bytes thanks to [@Stefnotch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/33160/stefnotch).

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by leaving out the brackets after console.log. `for(a=.5;;)console.log\`${a*=2}+1/\``   Though, your solution is limited by the language, because a is a float, not a big integer. (The challenge says that it should not be limited by the language, but rather by the system's specs.)

Comment: @Stefnotch That [doesn't work](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-babel-node#Sy1LzNFQj/mfll@kkWirZ2ptrZmcn1ecn5Oql5OfnqBSnahla1SrbaifoP5fryi1ICcxOVVD3dpaXUdB3TrRxjDVzFpdU9MaSY@Gup6enrrmfwA) unfortunately, because tagged templates with interpolation pass more than a single argument. I added the note about limitedness though, thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not testing my code. Well, this code does shave off 2 bytes: `for(a=1;;a*=2)console.log(a+"+1/")`

Comment: @Stefnotch Oh, and it's a lot simpler, too :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 19 bytes

```
1{.'+1/'+puts.+.}do
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@29Yraeubaivrl1QlJlXoqetV5uS//8/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 14 bytes

```
1{_o"+1/"o2*}h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29YHZ@vpG2or5RvpFWb8f8/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 bytes

```
1:n"/1+"ooo2*!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@29olaekb6itlJ@fb6Sl@P8/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```ruby
a=1;a*=2while$><<a<<'+1/'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@59oa2idqGVrVJ6RmZOqYmdjk2hjo65tqK/@/z8A)

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
cat(i<-1);repeat cat("+1/",i<-i*2)
```

Spacing is a bit werid but I understand that's ok.

Comment: You can use `repeat` instead of `while(T)`: `cat(i<-1);repeat cat("+1/",i<-i*2)` for 1 byte less.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
#h~hyZ"+1/
```

`Z` starts out as zero. `~hyZ` post-assigns the value of `2*Z+1` to `Z`. Thus, `Z` becomes `0, 1, 3, 7, 15, ...` over successive iterations. `h` then prints out the value one greater. `#` runs the infinite loop, and `"+1/` gets the  formatting right.

Answer (score 4):

## Vim, <s>22</s>, 21 bytes/keystrokes

```
qqyiwA+1/<esc>p@"<C-a>@qqxX@q
```

While testing this, you might run into issues with the current register values. To fix this, run

```
:let @q=''
:let @"=''
```

before running this, or by launching vim with

```
vim -u NONE -i NONE
```

Comment: absolutely beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>37</s>32 bytes

```
BEGIN{for(;;)printf 2^i++"+1/"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@@/k6u7pV52WX6RhbV2hZWukWVCUmVeSplBhr6RtqK9UYVVha1j7/z8A)

Could remove the `BEGIN` and save 5 bytes if input were allowed.
Using exponents definitely cheaper byte-wise than multiplication.  :)

Hopefully 2^1023 is close enough to infinity (on my work computer).  Unfortunately the TIO link truncates earlier than that (around 921). But 17726622920963562283492833353875882150307419319860869157979152909707315649514250439943889552308992750523075148942386782770807567185698815677056677116184170553481231217950104164393978236130449019315710017470734562946173533283208371259654747728689409291887821024109648618981425152 does seem pretty close to infinity. :)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 32 Bytes

```php
for(;;)echo bcpow(2,$i++)."+1/";
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/898c95a59617927db2bb412aebfe4c75eec5522b)

-6 Bytes if values like `9.2233720368548E+18` are allowed

```
for(;;)echo 2**$i++."+1/";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVTJQsv6fll@kYW2tmZqcka9gpKWlkqmtraekbagPlPoPAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 34 bytes

```
for([bigint]$i=1;;$i*=2){"$i+1/"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@5@WX6QRnZSZnplXEquSaWtoba2SqWVrpFmtpJKpbaivVPv/PwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>102</s> 100 bytes

Go can be almost as bad as Java, apparently.

```
import(."fmt"
."math/big")
func main(){n:=NewInt(1);for{Print(n.String()+"+1/");n.Mul(n,NewInt(2))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#K0hMzk5MT1XITczM@5@ZW5BfVKKhp5SWW6LEpaeUm1iSoZ@Uma6kyZVWmpcMVqShWZ1nZeuXWu6ZV6JhqGmdll9UHVCUCeTk6QWXABnpGpraStqG@kqa1nl6vqU5Gnk6UNVGmpq1tf//f83L101OTM5IBQA) (*Would be a good idea to avoid running any of these locally.* :P)

Comment: No, not as bad as Java: Go is 5 bytes shorter :P

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>107</s> 102 bytes

```
()->{for(java.math.BigInteger z=null,o=z.ONE,n=o;;n=n.add(n))System.out.print(n.max(o)==o?1:"+1/"+n);}
```

`z=null` exists to shorten the `o=java.math.BigInteger.ONE` into `z=null,o=z.ONE`, saving 12 bytes. `z.ONE` will not throw a `NullPointerException` because we access a static member and not an instance one.

Using `int` shortens the code, but fails to comply after 32 iterations.

### Saves

- 107 -> 102 bytes: `n.compareTo(o)>0` turned into `n.max(o)==o`, thanks to an idea given by @Shufflepants

Comment: This looks like one of the only entries that attempts to meet the rule: ""Infinitely" means no unnecessary delays, and for as long as possible limited by the current (variable) system's specs, but not limited by your current language." but it still doesn't do that because BigInteger still has a max value of 2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE).

Comment: @Shufflepants Where is that limit written? [Nowhere](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) ("may support values outside of that range"), so it's not a limitation of the language, but a limitation of the JVM, which then *is* the system. Also, "works on my computer", so good enough for codegolf ;)

Comment: If the implementation of a language or the JVM is considered part of the system and not the language, then you might as well use int instead of BigInteger.

Comment: No, because [`int` and all other primitive types are limited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html) at the language level. Also, the `BigInteger` doc explicitly says that a limit is optional, not mandatory (and that the default JVM implementation uses that limit).

Comment: This function "BigInteger max(BigInteger val)" exists in the specification too, which implies, that while the limit need not be what the current implementation limit is, it implies in the specification that there must be some finite limit.

Comment: That method means "take the biggest of the two numbers `this` and `val`". It's equivalent to `return this > val : this : val;`. So I honestly fail to see what you mean, sorry. I can't say anything more than what I quoted: a limit is optional :(

Comment: Sorry, got ahead of myself and misread it. Thought it was akin to Integer.MAX_VALUE but for BigInteger.

Comment: No problem. Thanks on making me double-check my code, I prefer a 100% compliant code when possible :)

Comment: @Shufflepants There, you got me golfing more when showing me the `max` method ;)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

Saved 2 bytes, thanks @DanielM !
Saved 1 byte, thanks @eush77 for pointing it out.

<s>*=console.log;a=1;*(1);for(;;)_(`+1/${a*=2}`)</s>

<s>*=console.log;*(a=1);for(;;)_(`+1/${a*=2}`)</s>

```
_=console.log;for(_(a=1);;)_(`+1/${a*=2}`)
```

My first go at Codegolf, go easy!

Comment: I was going to edit a snippet in for you, but then I broke my browser and remembered this is an infinite loop question xD

Comment: Yeah, had to restart my dev tools a couple times doing this!

Comment: The `a=1` can go in the first part of the for, `for(a=1;;)` saving you a byte in extra semicolon.

Comment: `_(a=1)`, work's with DanielM's suggestion too

Comment: @eush77 That doesn't create the right output imo. It will always have a trailing `+1/`, not a fraction.

Comment: @JakeTaylor You see, but it's infinite! It doesn't matter because every `1/` is followed by a number, it just happens to be printed on a next iteration of a loop. Given infinite amount of time, the output will be the same.

Comment: True, but it still feels incorrect, imo. I'll settle for 43 bytes.

Comment: @JakeTaylor I posted my solution separately.

Comment: @JakeTaylor I don't think you actually implemented DanielM's proposal though, with both DanielM's and  Felipe's I think it should be `_=console.log;for(_(a=1);;)_(\`+1/${a*=2}\`)` (-1 byte)

Comment: Ah, yes. I'll edit again.

Answer (score 3):

## C#,  ̶6̶8̶ 154 bytes

```
void A(int b=1){System.Console.Write($"1{(b>1?"/"+b:"")}+");A(b*2);}
```

Here is a version not constrained by int

```
using System.Numerics;BigInteger b=new BigInteger(1);void A(){System.Console.Write($"1{(b>1?"/"+b:"")}+");b=BigInteger.Multiply(new BigInteger(2),b);A();}
```

Comment: Stops working very quickly once the denominator hits `int.MaxValue`

Comment: @Rob what should the behavior be?

Comment: Here's an example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/infinitely-print-zenos-dichotomy-paradox-1-2n/120863#120863

Comment: Okay thanx, the new version should be sufficient.

Comment: As-is, nothing is actually printed because there's no call to A(); outside of the recursive call in the function. Also, BigIntegers have implicit conversions from primitive numeric types and built-in operators. So you can shave a lot (54 bytes?) off by changing the initial declaration to just `BigInteger b=1;` and shortening the multiplication to `b*=2;`

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge 93: 14 bytes

```
1:.2*"/1+",,,#
```

Comment: [Doesn't seem to be working on TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@29opWekpaRvqK2ko6Oj/P8/AA). Is it written for some specific implementation?

Comment: @eush77 Looks like TIO expects a fixed 80 char width grid, causing the "#" to skip empty space instead of the next instruction. I usually test [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), where the torus is  adjusted to the size of the actual code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
o©1“+1/”Ḥɼß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//b8KpMeKAnCsxL@KAneG4pMm8w5///w)

### How it works

Jelly's parsing rules are very complicated and depend on the arities of the link. Usually, links are composed of collections of:

- Dyad-nilad pairs (arities `2, 0`) such as `÷4` (divide by 4)
- Nilad-dyad pairs (arities `0, 2`) such as `3<` (greater than 3)
- Monads (arity `1`) such as `L` (length)
- Dyad-monad and monad-dyads (arities `2, 1` and `1, 2`) such as `+H` or `H+` (both \$n + \frac n2\$)

However, sometimes (very rarely), the arity patterns don't make sense. This is referred to an "unparseable" link. One such example is

```
4 H 5 Ḥ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99EwUPBVOHhjiX//wMA)

The arities here are `0, 1, 0, 1`, and the second nilad doesn't fit into any of the patterns. In this case, `5` is called an "unparseable nilad", and it causes the program to output the previous value (`4H`, or `2`) and discard it, using the `5` as the new link value. This causes the program about to output `210` (`4H` outputs `2` and `5Ḥ` outputs `10` at the end of the program)

The arities of the program above are `2, 0, 0, 0, 1`. The pattern `0, 0, 0` is unparseable, meaning that the third and fourth links (`“+1/”` and `Ḥɼ`) are unparseable nilads

```
o©1“+1/”Ḥɼß - Main link f(n). Initially n = 0
o 1         - Replace 0 with 1
 ©          - Save this value into the register
   “+1/”    - Unparseable nilad; Output 1 and use "+1/" as the argument
        Ḥɼ  - Unparseable nilad; Output "+1/" and use the below result as the argument:
         ɼ  -   Run the previous command on the register, then save the result back into the register:
        Ḥ   -     Unhalve; Yield 2n
          ß - Recurse, yielding f(2n)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 18 bytes

```
?1{q=q*2?@+1/`';`q
```

Prints each term on a new line.

Explanation:

```
?1       Prints 1
{        Infinite loop
q=q*2    Doubles q, starts at 1*2=2
?@+1/`  Prints the string +1/ 
  ';`      without tabs, newlines or other terminators (code literal, ; is a QBIC function)
q        Also prints q
         The infinite loop is auto-closed by QBIC at EOF.
```

We can save a byte with a more liberal output format:

```
{?q,A,┘q=q*2#+1/
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 20 bytes

```
 pL*
pd12<
p"M"
1+1/
```

Prints the sequence without any spaces. When run, you won't see anything for a little while, because of buffering, run with `-F` to immediately see everything.

1. Pushes and prints a 1, then stores "+1/" in quick storage (the register).
2. Pushes a 1.
3. Multiplies by two, loads from the register, prints, duplicates, and prints.
4. GOTO 3.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
1//.n_:>(n~Print~"+";n/2)
```

Comment: Don't we have to print the `+`s as well as the numbers?

Comment: @GregMartin Fixed...

Answer (score 2):

### `Haskell` - <s>66</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> <s>51</s> 49 chars

```
import Data.List
main=print$intercalate" + 1/"$map(show.(2^))[0..]
```

This prints the string constructed by printing the string representations of the powers of two starting from 1, separated by the string `" + 1/"`.

The code itself is 49 bytes, the import and newline push it up to 66

### Edit: (62)

Shaved 4 bytes by cutting out the import and defining intercalate with a much shorter name

```
f(x:xs)s=x++s++xs`f`s
main=print$map(show.(2^))[0..]`f`" + 1/"
```

### Edit 2: (60)

Shaved 2 more characters by realizing I didn't need to use the (x:xs) list convention:

```
f(x:y)s=x++s++y`f`s
main=print$map(show.(2^))[0..]`f`" + 1/"
```

### Edit 3: (51)

Reimplemented the definition of f and the map as the body of a fold to save 9 more characters

```
main=print$foldr((++).(++" + 1/").show.(2^))""[0..]
```

### Edit 4: (49)

As was pointed out by Laokoni, I can remove the spaces to cut down 2 more bytes off the total:

```
main=print$foldr((++).(++"+1/").show.(2^))""[0..]
```

Comment: The challenge states that spaces in the output are optional, so you can save another two bytes.

Comment: Also noticed that the most recent version is the same number of bytes as the original would be if "intercalate" was in the Haskell base library.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes because I realised I don't need the spaces, always read the spec thoroughly kids*

```
1!_V"+/">!@R.[<!_>2*v<!@>R!_v!@R<1+>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#1Rpdb9u69d2/gsmWWWps1@7dk@NkBYYWuA/DhmIoBrheoEqUzVWWPFF2HWzYX8/OISnySKISu8USrEBbkzw8318k9ZiWxZbJB8nEdleUFYvK9eFmoGbTfR5XRZHZtZIn@5ib1bjIMh5XosjtesL/uYdlMyrkZBdVGzfe8TKqitJOiIqXCr@dKaM8KbY3g0GcRVIyqRAG6t9wPmBAIGX392tewdbt/X0geZaOmMgTflTrjImUCSlyWUV5zAO1MmIyEzE3AAykqPZlzqqHHVcIwsAyMhEKlOKdAKqycoNi537zXRgOCErF6KSPwcEAUMXfJLtly9XNIN6XpZqA8fRmwPMEfnyMMgka3JVc8vLA3Uxc5Adg0k2UHMaSQMiqFPnajbmMox1Z3@6zSuwAhiCR38TOjURKWJAi4xQ0zRToX0u0cFYUZN@65Dx5cGNcVVrTkimacbFX2C4vDSfxJirNeIBmRatVgVRWqsoHY001RVWM9GHMjzHfVexzlO35h7IsyjkFUnxotNrpeFA734ilAtQOPsFBpYkiZ3bVIEETwvAHNlXWOkRZoH6MWG2lEWA4KEzgffVkgyG1YTldIQDAMg78mcnxDHyBqZnulsmu2GU8rYKwuxPXAg938kn2wKh6PWR3bGZjpsk1Y0gUrPM834pjsd446JkX@p2BdnI2iZwiqYfaadsc0X5Rm0JM@9nt0Nc0jNkChBppoLZxAmWEdVZ8jTK9XZKdemJp08LK7Ibw2fL7NIJUXMog14YE@u/gfzOrMgoMv28gaGHxDfxd3LLcypyzKyZqOQS7vmWzjng5e/v2lgkzMpgn0W4HmSkQ4cAgsl7TgshDJ4pZMvxHkKaCuEh0BlbZIBj@BWYxXV3JIfCmVlEXKvTqrGjSv1owrovVCT33F8ODAweZcHH5y3xF4B0A7prqXYaFX/PdvpobDpY4JUKWFiUoSOQUNdaUleLiqDOax4j6V60MQpZAW9OSOYAmo9o36Sad@MmMyfwNNjD1U6wq95MJl/zpNsj@ZAjpny6q/E8msACQISZ5MtQ1oLWuikBDvLoStFnDanBjPfjIFsp61mmMfkH7LpZ0gMYwh2DLo4nYo/JuiB3lH2DNB7QmNBZrHkxHLv3ZdgCsq2P@ARKXZHlRYdmpV5lbvNXlyAxDQwK3gx4JNmDplg3/PWRAXP@eDwm6RsmtZxulV0@B4SuRY7Wt6aBKO3RWBLcVBTK29XYqBcyPlXbcArp0w1b6D80MKvk1Kn4Lr8vCbqnLvvNBIoQu@3HoaJF2ASwZ@zD6WKwbDETnUIQ641uMqjrMqN6VwbWzU3lNjhhO/lGIPFjGmzIQil9wzdls9vvZ7J1GNiU5QyvZ@dhYEZ2vVuEIA/12OAw7pNvlyCqVlgJbl@Zt5KrYatkWtLjrMkgSqP7jawKdyO2m0/LT6gU9pjKdnPVCTEgdX70cMmjwldg6Q9Eoa3avDVWgIyyLMmkkaJs3Vi3xSGdZO4rl4MuXZrj4WGHMts662/W5m6PknFTT0fm6htTxYcoCihCHIYnwZk/fYnbu1AX5wWL8Rhrx1o7LoaNr9OmFux8S2yB@nb6deNBHkmTb1/NiGQpPDibA4gmDc72uaYZm6FGavczU7Jwk3E8zTJR@@5zSNV@dTkSngNCvAKGOjdObhkZkZffJrh0uryR2PZfQ9eABecQ8FFdhSLM8UrluFI72ma8l6/vnZG0kov4wQzduxPJTJlfAGI5PJOsfz786ly5XJ7mC1jQy5PGgZ3T3G6s7lyC8UfyfobvSqC8DvIC/dWmhdlEv3Og5q/UcII1hsOntHoysUtVx@ol1mikVrv5lezT3@0xP9XRWNPpK6l7wZNv8zmrIAno1ORl6C4A9OoedHf@yO@zth468nWpq4KgSNJ0X5hrax25zg3HRWvDVoA0Vud3qNcDHM6dlfefy4c8fyY1L/wYiW@bXBmnGO1sSu@UHSlFfXHbuzNqqg4DFMhX2yKZa1Y2H29IvoL7OnOB/9QHkNEHCTqRN2wnsLBkJq5LGuCPxk6W/PxP26NymGCDQ63zT070U0SHni1pTHjf83LSSPa3XbbJrzMjVrFWRDNm4roAE6cFla7LL/b5ms1rUWhWKPwcxdnUVsdr5uwZxctJpXhx7di7o2e8cYWKvc0iV6lUvapHNT6rHKhFPV@4WqdXYy0nJt8WBB@6upFdGwuafnmDz5R0558eq1@7UKIRTcFgdz22FLC02qzVMSB0VbP8PVDBuq8CmMa8fnq@ET1QJHtd82ot2P1dixJbjxWvzetaxSQOjKCvoNfSW3trSFW9vGcz5d9@l6FPhp9pffZllt9PgrOe6senrn2roDo9Hf@Xbiv7S/reeLdGxd8sffsZUqldSx88Qb8Wnnbs4evyor@Lo3I@W2qXl2tyeUaT0kezY2Xp9wgFdNhUhT4ntZivYehubREkyqnUllzO8trKjKRwJT0gSnlacHJ7kfmtsvDq95377KrpIwUBlIg7/W4XoF3Uf1bPV9OZV1ATn@JfVkCJ4tnLGr6Icuf/6sspRBM9Wzt9fRTm74vvLKkcRPFs5V68TVkXywmGFBM9QTvvdpntO9pTxC6tLwrT3/mTR6hHKokL9@C4X7vygHsgbC6k/ttGUB97HqfOfk7wXzr5npJMejMIG0vYlpbVmz6OQ3tz32OP3mO7tdf0@kif03Zxc3/XdUqjbzkHjyX6hn@zt0zt4skjwxV5e6KtRs/LHoix5XLG9jNYcr6nZIs2i9R1byGJfxvyOLfUPtXf1JUfGDMicfRDVhpdsnOLb6zie4C@RJyIGj5Cs2kSVwyMki1iKz81Vwb5yCNEoYfhl28i8Qo/jp/Z@LSORr4ssVc/PNY59PsGvCdSXCFMdSPwo1NXdYItw5isF/HjGyGFm8AMZVJmGwpKVDqnGmNwU@yxBEsAM11QF/gZmUIz6SwaN1nxNAQaItkhDzxqrmi/zJkIiRFCDmWD@DkrEj6HArhoVi4CCdb2a63SCGqsPIvorD0LbpR8jwUfU6ZV@YE/BS5ML5NbSNtFaK0uFrdNF/IQuQH5Uhkf@FlM1Sy0nROcxTmjIPz4@juPH2cX958vrt5d3F@8/TZaLi/u7d28Oi4v3d58u7g8wt5hd363@Cw)

Can probably be golfed better, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua 5.1](https://www.lua.org) + BC, 50 bytes

Now works with arbitrary long integers.

I don't usually golf in Lua, so any tips are welcome

```lua
i=1::a::print(i,'+1/')i=require"bc".mul(i,2)goto a
```

Comment: You can omit some newlines to save bytes.

Comment: You can use `while 1 do` instead.

Comment: @LeakyNun that will output garbage in the output when overflow happens

Comment: But then your answer does not print infinitely...

Comment: @LeakyNun original spec said thar language limitation could end the execution as well, i'll check

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista That's current spec not original spec.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer i didn't see the change, when internet is back i'll figure something out

Comment: To clarify: original spec (and now current again) is that infinity must be longer than a language limitation. You cannot be limited by your language, but you can be limited by your system.

Comment: internet is back, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

## Fourier, 20 bytes

```
1~io(43a1o47ai*2~io)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#@29Yl5lvFGBoYKBhYpxomG9inpipZQQU0/z/HwA)

I think this may only work on Try it Online due to differences in how Python and Javascript handle large numbers.

***Explanation Psuedocode:***

```
i = 1
Print i
While i != 0
    Print "+1/"
    i = i * 2
    Print i
End While
```

Comment: Can you not move the `Print i` to the start of the `While` loop?

Comment: @Neil I could, but it wouldn't say any bytes

Comment: Oh, I see now, you're not actually printing `i`.

Answer (score 1):

## **Ruby 46 bytes**

```
i=1;loop{print (i<2?"#{i}":"1/#{i}")+"+";i*=2}
```

any improvement suggestions are welcome -))

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 39 bytes

```
let rec f x=printf"%A+1/"x;x*2I|>f
f 1I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fs-mono#@5@TWqJQlJqskKZQYVtQlJlXkqak6qhtqK9UYV2hZeRZY5fGlaZg6Pn/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 25 bytes

```
)
:}!43.4
"     9
*{2.74.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@6/JZVWraGKsZ8KlpAACllxa1UZ65iZ6//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), <s>45</s> 57 bytes

Using shell:

```
$(eval 1?=1)$(info $1+1/)$(call $0,$(shell expr $1 \* 2))
```

Using [GMSL](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) (a lot slower, calculates in unary), a complete makefile — 66 bytes:

```
include gmsl
P=$(info $1+/)$(call P,$(call double,$1))
$(call P,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 42 bytes

```
(do((x 1(* x 2)))(())(format t"~a+"(/ x)))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#@6@Rkq@hUaFgqKGlUKFgpKmpqaEBxGn5RbmJJQolSnWJ2koa@goVQIn//wE) (TIO will show you partial output)

#### Explanation

```
(do ... )          ;looping
((x 1(* x 2))      ;define x as 1 and then in new interation steps 
                   ;as result of 2 * x
(())               ;no ending condition
(format t"~a+"...) ;print argument and "+"
(/ x)              ;divide 1 by x - output is like this: 1, 1/2, 1/4, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 29 bytes

```
for($a=.5;$a*=2;)echo"$a+1/";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
a=1;a/=2r while$><<a<<?+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@59oa2idqG9rVKRQnpGZk6piZ2OTaGNjr/3/PwA)

Heavily based on [G B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120820/69467). But rationals are fun :V

Answer (score 1):

## MSX-BASIC, 36 bytes

```
1?"1+":X=2
2?"1/";X;"+":X=X*2:GOTO2
```

It works up to 70368744177664, then it starts displaying the values in exponential notation due to the precision limitation of the language, then it overflows at 1e62.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 916 bytes

```
2 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.'1' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:w 1 r 3 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to Starchild Numerology:s 1 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:e 1 l 2 r.[r]Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.Go to Multiplication Station:e 1 r 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:s 1 r 2 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.' + 1/' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:s.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Fueler Up:n.Go to Post Office:s 1 r 1 l.Go to Trunkers:s 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:w 2 r.Switch to plan "r".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#nVJNT4QwEP0rk71wMMGAnjiqcU/qJqvxYDzUOsBka0umJWR/PZYCRgnBwKFpOh/vvem8NgWy0AhypAsQDo5OsCxJfcJj/YVslCnOcZREk7JXJoccWbjDyrh4b8CZSTBrIAGGK1CQgooPJE91BQIqYS3qAhkK06H5xoOxDp7ynCQOUL8imQ44qT@Jx@nzczIzGwp9UTj/kd6epTJ6JBxeGQ69HL/x@1L7M9f6hGwXOR5q5ahSJIUjozvV3T1QjghB9zjYfEeQxXC9aSQ7/F8/1ga5i99QItyID1Q52RLZewUuILnc4he70iNT6j9G4ZVg9zUqX/FSZXrGgj/Omltdn1i/lybs49iQk2UXr5TQsONd3Lbf) (TIO will output the first 893 terms (up to ~3.3×10²⁶⁸) before cutting it off.)

Ungolfed:

```
2 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
'1' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: west 1st right 3rd left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
Go to Starchild Numerology: south 1st right 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: east 1st left 2nd right.
[r]
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to Trunkers: south 1st left.
Go to Multiplication Station: east 1st right 4th left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: south 1st right 2nd left 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
' + 1/' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: south.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to The Babelfishery: north 1st right 2nd right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Fueler Up: north.
Go to Post Office: south 1st right 1st left.
Go to Trunkers: south 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: west 2nd right.
Switch to plan "r".
```

Explanation:

```
Pickup the string `1` and print it to stdout to get started.
Pickup the number `2` and duplicate it so we have one to keep around and one to print.
Abuse the truncation function to leave a `2` for later.
(It's en route and has a short name so it saves bytes which is really important in Taxi.)
Go multiply the running total by 2.
(The first time, it's just a `2` so it returns itself. After that, it's 2 times the running total.)
Pickup the string ` + 1/`.
Convert the multiplication result from a number to a string.
Get gas.
Print the string ` + 1/` and the string multiplication result to stdout.
Go pickup that `2` from Trunkers, copy it again, and go back to `[r]`.
```

The output has trailing zeros on every number: `1 + 1/2.000000 + 1/4.000000 + ...` but, per [a comment by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/infinitely-print-zenos-dichotomy-paradox-1-2n?noredirect=1#comment297908_120796), that's OK so long as it's the same number of zeros every time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 26 bytes

```
oruUroorp"/1+"1>O2uw"wo;;q
```

A fairly linear program.  Push characters `/1+` onto the stack, push 1 onto the stack.  Start loop, output number, multiply it by 2, push it to the bottom, pop the multipliers, output the characters on the stack and loop.

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgbyByIHUKICAgICAgVSByIG8KICAgICAgbyByIHAKIiAvIDEgKyAiIDEgPiBPIDIgdSB3ICIKdyBvIDsgOyBxICogLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=&speed=20)

Maps to

```
      o r u
      U r o
      o r p
" / 1 + " 1 > O 2 u w "
w o ; ; q * . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 59 bytes

```clj
#((fn[n](print(if(= 1M n)1(str 1\/ n))\+)(recur(* n 2)))1M)
```

A function that prints the fraction, doubles the denominator, then recurses.

```clj
(defn zenos-dichotomy-paradox []
  ; Create an anonymous function...
 ((fn [n]
    ; ... that prints the fraction (or just 1 if (= n 1))...
    (print
      (if (= 1M n) 1 (str 1 \/ n))
      \+)
    ; ..., doubles the denominator, then recurses infinitely.
    ; Will not SO since I'm using recur.
    (recur (* n 2)))
   ; Start the recursive function off with a 1. The M makes it a BigInteger so
   ;  I don't get an IntegerOverflow.
  1M))
```

Outputs

```clj
1 +1/2 +1/4 +1/8 +1/16 +1/32 +1/64 +1/128 +1/256 +1/512...
```

I can make the spacing more consistent at the cost of 2 bytes if necessary.

I tried to be clever and abuse Clojure's built in Ratio number type, but I got an overflow pretty quickly. `1/1` would have been automatically simplified to `1`, getting rid of `1` as a special case. It would have been nice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
J'+ms:1İ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/30tdO7fYyvDIhkN7//8HAA)

due to a lack of a 0 term, 1 is manually prepended.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt#L187), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ïóoù+1/q∟
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w@sOb8w/v1DbUL3zUMf//fwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
        ∟  # Do-while true without popping:
ï          #  Push the 0-based loop index
 ó         #  Pop and push 2 to the power this index
  o        #  Output it with trailing newline (without popping)
   ù+1/    #  Push string "+1/"
       q   #  Pop and push without trailing newline
```

Unfortunately MathGolf doesn't output implicitly even if it errors when we stop the infinite program, otherwise the `o` and `q` would have been unnecessary, because everything on the stack is joined and output implicitly at the end of a (properly terminating) MathGolf program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint`, 26 bytes

```perl
print 2**$_++,'+1/'while 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRMFIS0slXltbR13bUF@9PCMzJ1XB8P//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX2TMtOB6gA)

Using `bigint` means that this could go on forever without turning into a floating point exponential format, given enough time and RAM.  TIO gets to about 1/2<sup>922</sup> before cutting off due to the 128 KiB output limit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â─$∩√Öu
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83c424effb9975&i=)

same idea as 05AB1E, but Stax has more convenient output here :)

### Explanation

```
Wi^p"+1/
W        loop forever
 i^      increment counter
   p     print without newline
    "+1/ print "+1/" without newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```
1 [ dup "%u+" printf 2 / t ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQll@Um1hSkpmXrgCkMxSyU4vyUnMUrP8bKkQrpJQWKCiplmorKRQUZeaVpCkYKegrlCjEKuTk5xf8/w8A)

- `1` Push `1` to the stack.
- `[ ... t ] loop` The shortest infinite loop available in Factor.
- `dup "%u+" printf` Non-destructively write the prettyprinted form of an object with a "+" afterward.
- `2 /` Divide by two. In Factor, `/` produces an exact `ratio` as long as its inputs are rational. Use `/i` for integer division or `/f` to force the result to be a float.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zephyr](https://github.com/dloscutoff/zephyr), 52 bytes

```
set i to 1
while 1=1
print i,"+"
set i to i/2
repeat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0otyKgs@v@/OLVEIVOhJF/BkKs8IzMnVcHQ1pCroCgzDyiso6StxAVXkKlvxFWUWpCaWPL/PwA)

Gotta love built-in rational numbers.

For +3 bytes, output with all spaces (no newlines): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0otyKgs@v@/OLVEIVOhJF/BkKs8IzMnVcHQ1pCroCgzDyiso6StpKenxwVXk6lvxFWUWpCaWPL/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
Row@Flatten@Table[{1/2^t,"+"},{t,0,Infinity}]
```

Comment: This will not finish computing, and nothing will be printed.

Comment: Yes, I made it this way in order to get the result in a row. If you want to see a result just test for a finite number. Do you have any other ideas of how to print in a row?

Comment: You can use newlines as delimiters

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 13 bytes

```
|+1/=1:2^($-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/v0bbUN/W0MooTkNF1/D/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
|+1/            Set sequence join to "+1/"
    =1          Set first item in sequence to 1
      :         Mode : (sequence)
       2^($-1   Each item in the sequence equals 2 to the power of the index (1-based) of the current item minus 1
             )  Implicit closing parenthesis
```